# Title and axis labels on a back to back barplot

Tags: r

I have a back to back barplot, does anyone know how i can change the code to add a overall title and label both X axis (PM2.5 and life expectancy? Also if possible i wish to remove the lines where the continents are labeled and they overlap the Eastern Mediterranean section. Thanks. `
Barplot code and data used below if anyone can help.

```
g.mid<-ggplot(life_bar,aes(x=1,y=Continent))+geom_text(aes(label=Continent))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=Continent))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=Continent))+
  ggtitle("")+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
    axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))

g1 <- life_bar %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = air_pollution_bar, aes(Continent, mn), fill = 'red') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) +
   scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip()

g2 <- air_pollution_bar %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = air_pollution_bar, aes(Continent, mn), fill = 'red') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) +
   coord_flip()

gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid))

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))

> life_bar
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Continent                mn
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Africa                 62.7
2 Americas               74.8
3 Eastern Mediterranean  71.5
4 Europe                 78.1
5 South-East Asia        71.6
6 Western Pacific        74.3
> air_pollution_bar
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Continent                mn
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Africa                 41.1
2 Americas               19.5
3 Eastern Mediterranean  47.0
4 Europe                 15.6
5 South-East Asia        37.7
6 Western Pacific        16.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
  life_bar <- data.frame(Continent = c("Africa", "Americas", "Eastern Mid", "Europe", "South-East Asia", "Western Pacific"), mn = c(62.7, 74.8, 71.3, 78.1, 71.6, 74.3))
air_pollution_bar <- data.frame(Continent = c("Africa", "Americas", "Eastern Mid", "Europe", "South-East Asia", "Western Pacific"), mn = c(41.1, 19.5, 47.0, 15.6, 37.7, 16.4))

g.mid<-ggplot(life_bar,aes(x=1,y=Continent))+geom_text(aes(label=Continent))+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))

g1 <- life_bar %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = life_bar, aes(Continent, mn), fill = 'red') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(),       
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) +
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip() + ylab("life expectancy")

g2 <- air_pollution_bar %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = air_pollution_bar, aes(Continent, mn), fill = 'red') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) +
  coord_flip() + ylab("2.5PM")

gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid))

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9), top = "Your title")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: 99% there, although the bars don't match with the continents. Think this wass an issue i had from before also